# Formatting OGR VRT file to convert CSV to KML?

Tags: kml, convert, ogr, csv

I am attempting to get a nice KML for simple review of POI/geocoding from a CSV. I a using ogr2ogr and a VRT. You can see the VRT file below, with two attempts to get this right.

Basically, the issue is using `ogr2ogr -f KML ...` with the VRT w/o renaming results in a lot of "SimpleData" tags in the KML.

I'd like to get some CSV fields as the KML Placemark "Name" and "Description", concatenated fields, actually. `-dsco NameField=RegionName` option in `ogr2ogr`, but I don't see a way to concatenate fields into name, e.g Street, City, State..

In the .vrt below, the `SrcSQL` field results in no records. It does open, but with layer info. The `Field` tag (when not commented out) does result all records with in the new alias, but the "name" is the only field that comes through, it drops all other fields.

Is there a way to concatenate fields using ?

Of course, perhaps ogr is not capable of concatenation ...

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="roofing-poi2">
        <SrcDataSource>roofing-poi2.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude"/>
<!--         <Field src="StreetAddress" name="name" /> -->
        <SrcSQL>SELECT StreetAddress as name</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Circumventing ogr2ogr for the first conversion, I've found a unix tool that will allow me to do this (https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson)

```
csv2geojson -lat "latitude" -lon "longitude" input.csv > intermediatefile.geojson
```

I use a constant name for the output file so it gets just overwritten a bunch of times, but now I can convert to kml

```
ogr2ogr -f KML output.kml intermediatefile.geojson
```