# Converting csv to kml/geojson using ogr2ogr or equivalent command line tools?

Tags: gdal, convert, coordinates, csv, ogr2ogr

I've just unsuccessfully tried to use `ogr2ogr` to convert CSV into KML like so:

```
ogr2ogr -f "KML" output.kml input.csv
```

The csv has "latitude" and "longitude" columns.

The attributes are all loaded but if you inspect the KML's text, the Coordinate elements are not being added so its not working.

I feel like this will work if I can inform gdal to interpret certain columns ("latitude", "longitude") as coordinates.

How might I do this?

Comment: found similar question here but its unanswered: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31051/how-do-you-format-an-ogr-vrt-file-to-best-convert-a-csv-to-kml. Yes, like this guy, I'm getting a lot of <SimpleData> elements too

Comment: think of accepting one of the answers, maybe your own ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [ogr2ogr csv documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890463/creating-geojson-from-csv-how-do-i-set-geometry-properties), you need to specify which fields contain the geometry in a [VRT file](http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html):

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="test">
        <SrcDataSource>test.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Save this as a file with VRT extension and use it as the source:

```
ogr2ogr -f KML output.kml input.vrt
```

The csv is specified in `<SrcDataSource>test.csv</SrcDataSource>`. So for this example:

1. open a text editor and save the first code block as input.vrt
2. put your csv (test.csv), in the same directory
3. open a console or command window, change to that same directory and run the ogr2ogr command shown above.

The same steps apply for different output formats, e.g. shapefile, geojson, etc.

Comment: where is the *.csv file in this equation? let me know how this works and I'll mark this as the correct answer as clearly it is the people's choice.

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: where does the `name="test"` field come from in the OGVRTLayer?

Comment: @DavidLeBauer you have to give the layer a name, so it is just named `test`.

Answer (score 12):

> Starting with GDAL 2.1, it is possible to directly specify the
>   potential names of the columns that can contain X/longitude and
>   Y/latitude with the X_POSSIBLE_NAMES and Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES open option.

From the [gdal csv format documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html) section "Reading CSV containing spatial information > Building point geometries"

So your code would be

```
ogr2ogr -f "KML" output.kml input.csv \ 
   -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Longitude \
   -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Latitude
```

You'll likely want to add `-oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO` to prevent `Latitude` and `Longitude` fields being written to your kml file.

Comment: Would like to mark this as the correct as this is exactly what I was looking for back then, but this isn't working for me: `FAILURE: Unknown option name '-oo'`

Comment: What's your `ogr2ogr --version`? It works for me in 2.1.2

Comment: `ogr2ogr --version #=> GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16`. Will update and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Circumventing ogr2ogr for the first conversion, I've found a unix tool that will allow me to do this (https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson)

```
csv2geojson -lat "latitude" -lon "longitude" input.csv > intermediatefile.geojson
```

I use a constant name for the output file so it gets just overwritten a bunch of times, but now I can convert to kml

```
ogr2ogr -f KML output.kml intermediatefile.geojson
```

That works. Still interested in learning how to do this with just ogr2ogr.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like creating of VRT file mentioned above, you can use [MyGeoData Converter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu/) - the import tool will create the VRT file automatically.  Coordinate column is detected if the attribute name of X coordinate is:

```
x, xcoord, xcoordinate, coordx, coordinatex, longitude, long
```

or the attribute name contains:

```
x_*, *_x
```

Similar for Y coordinate:

```
y, ycoord, ycoordinate, coordy, coordinatey, latitude, lat
```

or the attribute name contains:

```
y_*, *_y
```

After then you can convert your CSV file to KML, GeoJSON or to almost any vector format...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command line utility [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/) by doing:

```
csvjson --lat lat_column --lon lng_column data.csv | ogr2ogr -f "KML" data.kml /vsistdin/
```

The command `csvjson` reads in a CSV file and when passed parameters for columns containing latitude and longitude values outputs GeoJSON. The output can then be piped directly to `ogr2ogr` via its `/vsistdin/` parameter.