# Converting CSV file to GeoJSON while preserving data types?

Tags: geojson, convert

Assuming said csv file is properly structured with Latitude and Longitude.  I'm having problems find converters that won't mess up the data types (putting string around integers).

Comment: I think that this question is different from http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127518/convert-csv-to-kml-or-geojson-etc-using-ogr2ogr-use-latitude-and-longitude, because it talks about conservation of data types

Comment: You can't really talk about "messing up" data types, because CSV doesn't have data types: every value *is* a string. What you want is a tool that can *infer* data types, which can be error prone - eg, is a numeric identifier a number or a string?

Answer (score 7):

The most robust way to do this, is to use GDAL's ogr2ogr functionality. Since you know your datatypes, you can specify them in `VRT` file.

The [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html) has this to say about setting field types:

> Field (optional, from GDAL 1.7.0): One or more attribute fields may be
>   defined with Field elements. If no Field elements are defined, the
>   fields of the source layer/sql will be defined on the VRT layer. The
>   Field may have the following attributes:
>
> **name** (required): the name of  the field.
>
> **type**: the field type, one of "Integer", "IntegerList", "Real", "RealList", "String", >"StringList", "Binary", "Date", "Time", or "DateTime". Defaults to "String".
>
> **subtype**: (GDAL >= 2.0) the field
>   subtype, one of "None", "Boolean", "Int16", "Float32". Defaults to
>   "None".
>
> **width**: the field width. Defaults to unknown. precision: the
>   field width. Defaults to zero.
>
> **src**: the name of the source field to be
>   copied to this one. Defaults to the value of "name". nullable (GDAL >=
>   2.0) can be used to specify whether the field is nullable. It defaults to "true".

So if your CSV data is like this:

```
 Latitude,Longitude,Name, Ht
 48.1,0.25,"First point", 3
 49.2,1.1,"Second point", 56
 47.5,0.75,"Third point", 67
```

You should build a VRT like this:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="data">
        <SrcDataSource>data.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude"/>
        <Field name="Name" src="Name" type="String"/>
        <Field name="Height" src="Ht" type="Real"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Now you can export to GeoJSON with the following command: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.geojson data.vrt`

Answer (score 3):

If you use geojson.io, it will not mess up the property data types.  Import the csv file into there, then export it out as geojson.

Comment: I tried with the sample CSV that I have mentioned in my answer, but geojson.io doesn't recognise the proper data types

Comment: I ran a csv through it with latitude and longitude and it maintained my timestamps and prices (properties) just fine.

Comment: It's just not robust enough. It didn't read the `Ht` in the CSV in my answer as numeric, and put in inverted commas around the values, making them strings.

Answer (score 1):

Taking CSV data (test.csv) from Devdatta Tengshe's answer:

```
Latitude,Longitude,Name, Ht
 48.1,0.25,"First point", 3
 49.2,1.1,"Second point", 56
 47.5,0.75,"Third point", 67
```

In QGIS you need a ***.csvt** file (test.csvt) for considering **data types**. In this case:

```
Real, Real, String, Integer
```

At the next imagen it can be observed that the csv layer 'type names' were loaded correctly:

[image]

Saving cvs layer as geojson directly:

[image]

Loading the geojson layer at the Map View of QGIS and  displaying the corresponding attributes table and the content of text file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://ogre.adc4gis.com/

Supports CSV and a number of other extensions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to recognise data types.

Answer (score 0):

Also [MyGeoData Converter](http://converter.mygeodata.eu) allows to convert CSV and many other formats to GeoJSON and other formats on-line. It is also possible to use VRT file mentioned above...