# Converting large CSV to line-delimited GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, csv, command-line

What is a good way to convert a large (100MB) CSV file to GeoJSON on the command line, preferably without GDAL? I tried Mapbox's [csv2geojson](https://github.com/mapbox/csv2geojson) but it ran out of memory.

Answer (score 6):

Since I'm comfortable with Node, I came up with this stream-oriented script. It's easy to transform values in the process.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fs = require('fs');
const turf = require('@turf/turf');

function rowToFeature(record, callback) {

    // Adjust these field names according to your file
    if (!(record.Latitude && record.Longitude)) {
        return;
    }
    let feature = turf.point([ +record.Longitude, +record.Latitude ], {
        myfield: record['My Input Field'],
        joinedfield: record.field1 + record.field2
        // ... etc
    });
    callback(null, JSON.stringify(feature) + '\n');
}

fs.createReadStream('infile.csv')
    .pipe(require('csv-parse')({ columns: true }))
    .pipe(require('stream-transform')(rowToFeature))
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('outfile'));
```

Before running:

```
npm init
npm install csv-parse stream-transform
```

Comment: +1 As a 'Node guy', I like this solution.  There is a useful module in the NPM repository called [dbGeo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dbgeo) which takes data usually from a DB query but it cold equally be a parsed CSV file and does a similar thing to this.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a job for CSVKit, my new favourite tool:

https://source.opennews.org/articles/eleven-awesome-things-you-can-do-csvkit/

**5. Turn a CSV with latitude and longitude columns into GeoJSON**

Is your data geographic, like in our previous example? Then don’t stop with JSON—go one step further and make it GeoJSON!

**`csvjson --lat latitude --lon longitude --key slug --crs EPSG:4269 --indent 4 geo.csv > geo.jso`**n

```
[geo.json]

{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "bbox": [
        -95.31571447849274,
        32.299076986939205,
        -95.28174,
        32.35066
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "dcl",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -95.30181,
                    32.35066
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "place": "Downtown Coffee Lounge"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "tyler-museum",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -95.28174,
...
```

Reference: [csvjson](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvjson.html)

Comment: Thank you, that works. It's very slow though. On my 100MB file, it takes nearly 4 minutes whereas my script (which saves few properties) takes 35 seconds.

Comment: @SteveBennett what do you mean 'saves few properties'?

Comment: In my script, I'm stripping out properties that I don't want in the output. Using this tool keeps them. So it's maybe not a totally fair comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Another node solution that would require less coding than Steve Bennett's excellent solution would be to use the NPM Module called [csv2geojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv2geojson).

There is also another modules called [csv3geojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv3geojson).  This version purports to be faster than csv2geojson and supports streaming so maybe better in this particular use-case.  I can't vouch for it though as I have not used it, but certainly worth a look.

Also see [Converting CSV file to GeoJSON while preserving data types?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140219) which is a similar Q&A.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in the Q, csv2geojson ran out of memory for me. I tried to increase the maximum heap size with an environment variable but I'm not sure it had any effect. A streaming version would be likely to work.