# Checking maximum number of features for shapefile to be opened in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, limitations

I have a shapefile that contains 10,608,268 polyline features.

What is the maximum limit for records that a shapefile can contains?

Answer (score 5):

From the [ArcGIS Desktop help on Geometry limitations](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm#GUID-B845DF9F-78C9-439F-9674-2BFEEFF8D58E):

> There is a 2 GB size limit for any shapefile component file, which
>   translates to a maximum of roughly 70 million point features. The
>   actual number of line or polygon features you can store in a shapefile
>   depends on the number of vertices in each line or polygon (a vertex is
>   equivalent to a point).

I echo the [comment of @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286316/checking-maximum-number-of-features-for-shapefile-to-be-opened-in-arcmap/286318#comment458647_286316):

> There are several dynamic buffers involved. I could construct a
>   geometry which was too large to fit in a single [shape], or two that
>   would cause the second to overflow. In your case, 4000 bytes of
>   attributes would prevent creation over 536k features, no matter how
>   many vertices. Note that this isn't a limit of ArcGIS but of the
>   shapefile format itself. My recommendation: **Don't use shapefiles**. They
>   are archaic, with too many limitations with modern datatypes and
>   volumes.