# Reducing shx file size using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, vertices

I have a shp with size 673'476 KB, with shx size 192'422 KB (as shown in the picture below). This file is with points.

Is there any way that can I reduce the shx file size using QGIS?

[image]

Comment: The `.shx` file is fixed-width (with length `(100 + 8 * nrecs)`) and required. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348557/how-does-a-shapefile-2gb-limit-equate-to-70-million-points

Comment: If the singleton points share common attributes, you could convert them to mulitpoints, which would reduce the record count, and therefore the size of both the `.shx` and `.dbf` (you might get a little reduction in the `.shp`, or it might increase a bit, due to the cost of storing the envelope, depending on the vertex density in the multipoints).