# Geometry error in large dataset

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, topology

I have a large shapefile that I'm working on, containing more than 555.000 polygons, that represents the area covered by a 5G network. I have to extract areas that are not covered by a 5G network based on another shapefile (Local administrative units). I have tried with Difference, but it shows that the geometry is invalid. So I used Check validity, where it showed all kinds of error, but did not manage to resolve them. Now I'm trying the option of importing the shapefile into GRASS GIS, via v.in.ogr, but the loading has stopped after some time and now it's stuck in the same place for the last hour. I'm losing my mind and I don't know what to do anymore, does anyone know any other way how can I extract those areas or, any easier way to clean topology? I have also tried Fix topology, but it did literally nothing.

Comment: I would rasterize the polygon layer and analyze then the raster. NoData cells in the raster are those without 5G coverage. I bet that will be much faster.

Comment: Use a different vector format. Shapefile has a 2GiB file size limitation which is easily breached by buffer polygons. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348557/how-does-shapefile-2gb-limit-equate-to-70-million-points

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It turned out that the problem was in my laptop, it couldn't process the simple "fix geometries" command. I managed to fix geometries with no problems when I changed to better laptop with more RAM.